# Finding and displaying locations in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocation

I have the list of latitudes and longitudes.

I want to have a Map View that shows me the nearest one of these locations within a 10 mile radius and show them all to me.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: What? Please clarify your question.

Comment: As i mentioned before i have co-ordinetes in database, When user is loging in, should get current location, from this location should find the nearest location of database co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of mapkit tutorials out there on the web, such as http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial. Have you looked at these?